# Force write to Xcode 'Debugger Output' in console?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, lldb, xcode11

The Xcode console has a **'Debugger output'** filter. I understand this is for use with `lldb`, and that you can get messages to print to this output by using breakpoints. My question is not how to do that.

My question is: what is the underlying mechanism Xcode *itself* uses to write `lldb` messages to **Debugger Output** (*not* Target Output)? Is there a variable similar to `stdout` or `stderr` that writes here? Is it possible, from Xcode target code (Swift/Obj-C/C), to write to this output?

Comment: `NSLog` (Obj-C) & `print` (Swift). There's a button in the bottom/left corner where you can switch between All Output, Debugger Output and Target Output. Is this what you want?

Comment: No, by default those go to "Target Output" (and by extension, "All Output") - I'm asking how to direct output to "Debugger Output"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like Xcode uses a tty to communicate with lldb, and you can interface with the Debugger Output using that:

`echo "Wheeeeeeee" > $(lsof -p $(ps -A | grep -m1 MacOS/Xcode | awk '{print $1}') | grep -m2 dev/ttys | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}')`

Breaking the above down:

```
$ ps -A | grep -m1 MacOS/Xcode | awk '{print $1}' 
21280
```

This gives the process ID of Xcode (21280). Using this, we can find the files it has open:

```
$ lsof -p 21280 | grep /dev/ttys
Xcode   21280 tres   47u      CHR               16,3       0t0                3569 /dev/ttys003
Xcode   21280 tres   58u      CHR               16,5       0t0                3575 /dev/ttys005
```

The one with the highest number (`/dev/ttys005` in this case) is the one we want, so let's extract it. `tail -1` will give us the last line of output, and `awk '{print $9}'` will give us the 9th item on the line, which is what we want!

```
$ lsof -p 21280 | grep /dev/ttys | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'
/dev/ttys005
```

Now we can use this to write whatever we want:

[image]

Comment: Impressive  Is the other tty interface the Target Output?

Comment: Thanks and yep it is. Now to figure out how to write to it from the Simulator...

Comment: Any way to read from it as well? ```echo "Wheeeeeeee" > /dev/ttys004``` prints to ```Target Output``` in xcode so I though maybe ```tail -f /dev/ttys004``` would work... but it does not.