# Redirect console prints from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, stderr

While developping an app for an iPad on my Mac, I use print logs to monitor what is going on (regular `print`s in Swift code). However I really don't like the Xcode console, and I'd like to be able to redirect the stream to a file, where I can then read it with a better log viewer (and add color!).

I'm executing the app **in debug mode through Wifi on my iPad**, but I want the logs on my Mac, so storing the logs to a file on the device is not really interesting ([SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66515158/howto-print-console-output-to-both-file-console)). Wrapping the debugger executable seems interesting, as [suggested here](https://pastebin.com/aymnb9ce) but I couldn't find anything more recent (with lldb).

Alternatively, I could also run the debugger from the console and handler the redirection from there, but I don't know how to do that for debugging on a remote device over WiFi.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This could be a good starting point https://stackoverflow.com/a/62704700/5329717

Comment: Nice! It's really interesting. Do you have any idea how to capture / monitor what is written to any of these tty ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this https://github.com/rocasa/ttylog looks promising. Oh btw poor man's color in logs in XCode debug console can be Emoji ⚪️.

Comment: Thanks! I stumbled upon it, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be ported (or maintained?) on Mac. I had a look at the code but it's way too complex for me :) you have a point with emojis, but I also want to store the logs for later analysis for example.